# Spring-boot @ComponentScan not working when classes are packaged in a jar, working fine when classes are not packaged

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

- Spring version: 5.3.9
- Spring-boot version: 2.5.3

Here is an example of the hierarchy of my classes and packages:

```
my.app
   - MyApplication.class
     .data
      - MyDataRelatedComponent.class
     .service
      - MyServiceRelatedComponent.class
```

MyApplication has @SpringBootApplication and the other classes has @Service, @Component and etc and here is my directory structure:

```
/myapp/config/
      /libs/
```

*application.yml* is located in */myapp/config/* and jar files on which my app dependent are all located in */libs*.

When I package my classes in a jar using **Eclipse's JAR EXPORT** and locate it in /myapp/libs then execute as follows, Spring does not scan any of the bean candidate classes. It does not work.

```
java -cp /myapp/config:/myapp/libs/* my.app.MyApplication
```

When I make directory ***/myapp/classes*** and locate my classes here then execute as follows, Spring scans my bean candidate classes. It works fine.

```
java -cp /myapp/classes:/myapp/config:/myapp/libs/* my.app.MyApplication
```

After hours of Internet research, I think it would be solved if I use *spring-boot-maven-plugin*, however I cannot use Maven due to my company's security policy. Now I don't only want to execute my application, I also want to know what the exact problem is.

I think It's a *classpath* relevant problem. What am I missing?

Comment: #1 Are you using at least maven? Your main problem is the absence of spring-boot-maven-plugin. #2 sounds interesting to build and run an spring-boot build plugins #3 Do you have all the  required spring jars in your libs folder? #4 If you can, could you sharr us the reason behind the security police. Is the internet access restricted?

Comment: @JRichardsz #1 I can&#39;t use maven as I mentioned. #3 I have all required jar files. If not, It could have not ran correctly regardless of whether classes are package or not. It works just fine when classes are not packaged. #4 Yes, the company&#39;s build environment is not allowed for Internet access.

Comment: Is there a chance to share an entire .m2 folder with all the jar in maven format? Maven offer an option to do that, just for your case!. If usage maven is **impossible** for you, I think the maven father is for you: ant framework

Comment: @JRichardsz I do not understand why you are talking about maven. Maven is not an option I can take. There is no maven here. As I menthioned in the question above, this is not to just execute my app, to know exactly why it cannot work. If I just want to execute my app, I would just use classes, not jar packaging. This is the simplest  solution to execute my app.

Comment: @JRichardsz As well as maven, I do not need Ant because I already have all dependent jars I need. Eclipse or javac is enough for building my app and actually works fine.

Comment: Make sure that you export your classes into regular JAR, not Runnable JAR

Comment: @NikolaiShevchenko I'm extremely sure that it is a regular jar. This is why I emphasized the jar was packaged using 'Eclipse's JAR EXPORT', not 'Runnable JAR File Export'. My jar just contains classes in the package structure. nothing special. In fact I tried the same way of execution using a runnable jar too and It resulted the same, not working.

Comment: How do you configure the component scan? (Do you have just a `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class, or do you have also a `@ComponentScan` annotation) - In which package are the located, which this the root package of your libs.  (see https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using.html#using.structuring-your-code)  - _I do not think that the missing `spring-boot build plugin` is the problem, because to my knowledge it is just responsible to pack all jars in one file_

Comment: @Ralph I just use `@SpringBootApplication` to the class, `MyApplication`, which is in the `my.app` package and all other classes are in child packages of `my.app`.  There is no `@ComponentScan` annotated to particular classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what the problem was. This is not a complete answer I think, but close.

Spring scans resources using *PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver* and this class internally tries to get resources using *ResourceLoader's ClassLoader.getResources* or conditionally *ClassLoader.getSystemResources* with *"my/app"*, where MyApplication class is located, which is my Spring boot application's starting point.

The source code of *PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.doFineAllClassPathResources* is as follows:

```
ClassLoader cl = getClassLoader();  // Internal ResourceLoader's ClassLoader
Enumeration<URL> resourceUrls = (cl != null) ? cl.getResources(path) : ClassLoader.getSystemResources(path);
```

When executing the application with not packaged classes, *resourceUrls* contains an absolute file system path of the given path, *"my/app"*, however when  with classes packaged in a jar, it results in an empty Enumeration and Spring does not scan any of my classes which are located in child packages of *my.app*.

This is not a Spring thing. I tried to reproduce it with very simple example Java code without Spring like this:

```
resourcesUrls = Test.class.getClassLoader().getResources("my/app");
...
resourcesUrls = ClassLoader.getSystemResources("my/app");
...
```

The results are the same with the results of Spring. This is because classes are no longer independent files when packaged in a jar, they are binaries. I need to use *ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream* if I want to read resources in jar files.

I think Spring boot application is not intended to be packaged in this way. I guess Spring has its own technical solution for this and this is one of the reasons one should use Maven or Gradle plugin for packaging a Spring boot application.